# IQueryable selecionar dados de tabelas realacionadas .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, linq

Preciso fazer uma consulta no ASP.NET MVC utilizando o Entity Framework, onde ao informar um IDSubCategoria me retorne todos os produtos que estão classificados em categorias:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo:

Subcategorias:

[image: IDSubcategoria 1 / CERVEJA (idSub = 1)]

Categorias:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Produtos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, no exemplo, ao informar o Id = 1 da **SUBCATEGORIA**, preciso que me retorne os 4 itens da tabela produtos que estão relacionados com a tabela **CATEGORIA** que por sua vez está relacionada com a tabela **SUBCATEGORIA**.

so consigo listar relacionando 2 tabelas, no caso dessa busca abaixo informando o id da categoria e não da subcategoria:

```
var produtos = db.Produtoes            
               .Where(p => p.Categoria.IDCategoria == id)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: se o modelo estiver todo relacionado, pode usar o `Include()` para incluir outras tabelas, por exemplo `.Include(i => i.Categoria.Subcategoria)`, dependendo de como estão os nomes e os relacionamentos

Comment: O relacionamento esta na primeira imagem, ou seja, pesquisar uma subcategoria, vejo as categorias, só então tem os produtos categorizados.

nesse codigo, so consigo mostrar os produtos de uma determinada categoria, não sei como pesquisar de uma subcategoria no relacionamento que fiz

Comment: Conseguiu uma solução, @José?

Comment: sim, tinha somente que incluir a tabela de categoria:
var produtos = db.Produtoes
                         .Include(p => p.Categoria)
                        .Where(c => c.Categoria.IDSubCategoria == id);

Answer (score 1):

Presumo que você tenha as propriedades de navegação de cada entidade. Tendo isso, você pode ir na tabela de **Produtos**, incluir a **Categoria** e a **SubCategoria** relacionada com o método **Include** e buscar os produtos a partir da **SubCategoria** que deseja.

Dessa forma:

```
contexto.Produtoes
        .Include(p => p.Categoria.SubCategoria)
        .Where(p => p.Categoria.SubCategoria.IDSubCategoria == id);
```

Comment: Correto, Deu certo! Obrigado!